# Pure css3 parallax and mobile

Tags: html, ios, css, parallax

I'm using transform3D to achieve a pure css parallax effect.
I have a really messy demo setup here:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/nGAvw

This is the main code that does the translation:

```
transform: translateZ(-1px) scale(2);
z-index: -1;
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

I would like my parallaxed image to be clipped using overflow:hidden.
This works fine on desktop Chrome / Safari but stops working on Mobile Safari.
From my further experiments it works fine on Android but stops working on iOS7.

Any idea how to solve this?
Is there any way to clip translated object on iOS?

Comment: Do you try to use -webkit-, -moz-, -o- pseudo elements?

Comment: You need to use -webkit-

Comment: what is your parallaxed item, and what does "stops working" mean?

Comment: also, z-index only works on positioned elements e.g. relative.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to give a look at this example which works on Mobile Safari:

http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/pure-css-parallax-websites/

I've also reproduced it on Codepen to keep a track:

http://codepen.io/gyopiazza/pen/BazoG

And here is the code...

**HTML**

```
  <div class="parallax">
    <div id="group1" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group2" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">Background Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group3" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--fore">
        <div class="title">Foreground Layer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group4" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">Background Layer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--deep">
        <div class="title">Deep Background Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group5" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--fore">
        <div class="title">Foreground Layer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group6" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--back">
        <div class="title">Background Layer</div>
      </div>
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="group7" class="parallax__group">
      <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer--base">
        <div class="title">Base Layer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Parallax base styles
  --------------------------------------------- */

  .parallax {
    height: 500px; /* fallback for older browsers */
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    -webkit-perspective: 300px;
    perspective: 300px;
  }

  .parallax__group {
    position: relative;
    height: 500px; /* fallback for older browsers */
    height: 100vh;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
  }

  .parallax__layer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
  }

  .parallax__layer--fore {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.7);
    transform: translateZ(90px) scale(.7);
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .parallax__layer--base {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
    z-index: 4;
  }

  .parallax__layer--back {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
    transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(2);
    z-index: 3;
  }

  .parallax__layer--deep {
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
    transform: translateZ(-600px) scale(3);
    z-index: 2;
  }


  /* demo styles
  --------------------------------------------- */

  body, html {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  body {
    font: 100% / 1.5 Arial;
  }

  * {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
  }

  .parallax {
    font-size: 200%;
  }

   /* centre the content in the parallax layers */
  .title {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }



  /* style the groups
  --------------------------------------------- */

  #group1 {
    z-index: 5; /* slide over group 2 */
  }
  #group1 .parallax__layer--base {
    background: rgb(102,204,102);
  }

  #group2 {
    z-index: 3; /* slide under groups 1 and 3 */
  }
  #group2 .parallax__layer--back {
    background: rgb(123,210,102);
  }

  #group3 {
    z-index: 4; /* slide over group 2 and 4 */
  }
  #group3 .parallax__layer--base {
    background: rgb(153,216,101);
  }

  #group4 {
    z-index: 2; /* slide under group 3 and 5 */
  }
  #group4 .parallax__layer--deep {
    background: rgb(184,223,101);
  }

  #group5 {
    z-index: 3; /* slide over group 4 and 6 */
  }
  #group5 .parallax__layer--base {
    background: rgb(214,229,100);
  }

  #group6 {
    z-index: 2; /* slide under group 5 and 7 */
  }
  #group6 .parallax__layer--back {
    background: rgb(245,235,100);
  }

  #group7 {
    z-index: 3; /* slide over group 7 */
  }
  #group7 .parallax__layer--base {
    background: rgb(255,241,100);
  }
```

Comment: The small usability problem using this technique is that you can't scroll to the top by tapping the status bar.

Comment: Without yet having a solution, I just want to point out that this no longer works in mobile safari (at least on iPhones, seems to work in a hit or miss way on iPad). The issue seems to be that the use of 'overflow' styles completely messes up the transform styles, causing everything to become massive.

Comment: And here is confirmation of that: https://css-tricks.com/ios-13-broke-the-classic-pure-css-parallax-technique/