# Pure CSS Parallax Scrolling Effect on Chrome for Android

Tags: css, scroll, transform, parallax, perspective

Keith Clark wrote an [excellent, minimal demo](http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/demos/1/) demonstrating parallax scrolling effect using only CSS with `perspective: 1px`, `overflow-y: auto` and a container at `width: 100vw`.

However, if you go to that page with Chrome for Android (I have not tried other mobile devices, comments welcome), it does not work. I'm on Chrome 37.0.2062.117, Android 4.4.4, Nexus 4.

I have tried `-webkit-`. It does not work for the demo.

There is [one related question on the site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275153/pure-css3-parallax-and-mobile), but it also does not work on Chrome for Android—there is no parallax scroll on my phone.

Could anyone offer a solution based on the [demo](http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/demos/1/) that is pure CSS and works on Chrome for Android?

Comment: It's not just Chrome for Android. Not working on Chrome (M37) on Mac, either. [His blog post](http://blog.keithclark.co.uk/pure-css-parallax-websites/) mentions this at the top of the page and refers to how to correct it for the time being.

Comment: The demos are working flawlessly on Chrome Beta 38.0.2125.57 (Blink 537.36 @181577) on my LG Optimus 4X HD running Android 4.4.4, so it shouldn't be long until we see it working in Chrome stable.

Comment: Thanks. I can confirm that it works on Chrome M37 on Mac, so maybe I should just switch to Chrome beta.

Comment: Seems not to be working again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's just a bug in Chrome M37. Version 38 works just fine!

Answer (score 0):

http://www.skullysystems.com is the only website that I know of that has a solution that works on all browsers, I'm not sure if their is a library that they're using or if its a custom script they built. You could try reverse engineering what they've built.